# Jetty/Jersey: Find resource method from URI

Tags: java, annotations, jersey, jetty

I have an embedded Jetty/Jersey application with different resource classes. What I want is to annotate each resource method with some additional description and retrieve the correct method description based on the URI.

Some code:

```
@Path("resource1")
public class My1stResource {
    @GET
    @Path("/aMethod")
    @Description("This is a method")
    public static String getValue() 
    {
        ...
    }
}

@Path("resource2")
public class My2ndResource {
    @GET
    @Path("/anotherMethod")
    @Description("This is another method")
    public static String getValue() 
    {
        ...
    }
}

public class Whatever {
    private static Server server;

    public static void main(String args[]) throws DataException
    {        
        Set<Class<?>> s = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
        s.add(My1stResource.class);
        s.add(My2ndResource.class);
        ResourceConfig config = new ResourceConfig(s);     

        this.server = new Server(8765);

        ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.NO_SESSIONS);
        context.setContextPath("/");
        this.server.setHandler(context);

        ServletContainer container = new ServletContainer(config);
        ServletHolder apiServlet = new ServletHolder(container);
        apiServlet.setInitOrder(1);
        context.addServlet(apiServlet, "/api/*");
    }

    public static String GetDescription(String uri)
    {
        ???
    }
}
```

How can I retrieve the content of my @Description annotation in GetDescription? If this isn't possible: Is there some other mechanism I can use to achieve my goal?

Thanks,
Kc

Comment: A uri can have more than one resource method associated with it. For instance, each one can have a different `@Produces`, or a different HTTP method. How will you differentiate between these?

Comment: In the ideal case: exactly by checking those annotations. If I would get a collection of all matching resource methods, I could find the one I need by reflection.